# Testing if URL and querystring is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to test if a url & querystring is valid? For example, after a login redirect I want to make sure the target url is valid. If not, go to a default page.

We seem to have a problem with the querystring, starting with "ReturnUrl=", being duplicated and that throws an exception. We'd rather have it go to a default page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for too long `ReturnUrl` querystring parameter. The fact is if there was something in the querystring before appending new `RedirectUrl` parameter (e.g. by using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage` method), this would be encoded and assigned to the new `RedirectUrl` parameter.

The idea is to remove unnecessary(old `ReturnUrl` parameters from the querystring). For this I use `Application_EndRequest` in `global.asax` and `Response.RedirectLocation` property.

So if the response is being redirected and current url contains `ReturnUrl` parameter, it should be removed from redirected location (because it doesn't make sense).

```
// parameter key
private static readonly string ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    {
        Uri redirectUrl;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(Response.RedirectLocation, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out redirectUrl))
        {
            redirectUrl = MakeAbsoluteUriIfNecessary(redirectUrl);
            Uri currentUrl = Request.Url;
            var currentQueryParameters = 
                    HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(currentUrl.Query));
            // the parameter is present in the current url already
            if (currentQueryParameters[ReturnUrlParameter] != null)
            {
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(redirectUrl);
                builder.Query = 
                        HttpUtility.UrlDecode(builder.Query)
                            .Replace(Request.Url.Query, string.Empty).TrimStart('?');

                Response.RedirectLocation = 
                        Request.Url.MakeRelativeUri(builder.Uri).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

private Uri MakeAbsoluteUriIfNecessary(Uri url)
{
    if (url.IsAbsoluteUri)
    {
        return url;
    }
    else 
    {
        Uri currentUrl = Request.Url;
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(
                currentUrl.Scheme, 
                currentUrl.Host, 
                currentUrl.Port
            );

        return new Uri(builder.Uri, url);
    }
}
```

For URL parsing and building [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) will be the best choice.

> A URI is a compact representation of a
>   resource available to your application
>   on the intranet or Internet. The Uri
>   class defines the properties and
>   methods for handling URIs, including
>   parsing, comparing, and combining. The
>   Uri class properties are read-only; to
>   create a modifiable object, use the
>   UriBuilder class.

Comment: I looked into System.Uri. Unfortunately, even though a portion of the querystring is duplicated, the uri is still well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could extract the URL, Decode it, and then load it into a "Uri" Type. This would tell you if it is structurally sound.